# why does the program counter in 8051 is 16 bit and stack pointer is 8 bit in 8051?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

Why does the stack pointer holds only  8 bit address in 8051 and whereas the  program counter holds the 16 bit address?

Comment: that is the way it was designed.

Comment: It has only 128 bytes of RAM, so an 8-bit stack pointer is enough.  Using external RAM is possible, but requires a special instruction (MOVX).

Answer (score 3):

Every processor can have the width of its pointers deliberately designed. And both PC and SP are pointers, pointing to the instruction to be executed and saved contents on the stack, respectively.

The designers of the 8051 separated **instruction memory** and **data memory**. There are more memory sections, but the stack is located in the latter, so this should suffice.

- **Instruction memory:** It has a maximum size of 65536 bytes that can be accesses without further "tricks". To address this range you need 16 bits.
- **Data memory:** It has a maximum size of 256 bytes, even though the standard 8051 has only 128 of them implemented. To address this range you need 8 bits.

Please remember, **code** and **stack** are different things!

- **Code** contains all instructions (and if present constants.) It is mostly composed of ROM, but can be RAM.
- **Stack** stores return addresses and saved values. It has to be RAM.